# Cambiar permisos API Twitter a Read and Write

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-api, tweepy

Tengo una cuenta en Twitter Developers y quiero usar esa API para poder publicar Tweets con un algoritmo de python. Ya ha conseguido que me den el nivel Elevate en el proyecto, pero sin embargo a la hora de crear los tokens me los crea con el permiso 'Read Only' en vez de 'Read And Write'. En los ajustes de la aplicación solo me deja cambiar el nombre, icono y descripción de la app y en los tokens solo me deja regenerarlos nuevamente, concediéndome siempre 'Read Only'.
¿Dónde lo puedo cambiar?
Adjunto foto del apartado de los ajustes de la app[image: Solo me deja cambiar esta información]

Y aquí la foto de los ajustes de los tokens[image: En el apartado de Access Tokens es donde indica que únicamente tiene el permiso 'Read Only']

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está la respuesta. Por lo visto hace dos días cambiaron la interfaz y han modificado la forma en la que se puede cambiar los permisos de una aplicación:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/changing-app-permissions-missing-in-ui/163708/9

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y escribe brevemente un resumen del enlace del contenido que proporcionas. Ten en cuenta que tal contenido puede que ya no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo inválida esta respuesta. Lee [answer].